# Custom HTML footer in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am trying to create a letter template in TCPDF but struggling with the footer.

I have added the below

```
$footertext="Registered Charity no XXX. Company Limited by Guarantee registered in England and Wales no XXX. <br>
Registered Office: ADDRESS HERE";
```

And then added the below in the PDF create section

```
public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);   
    }
```

However nothing shows?

Comment: Who is `$this` in your current code? Can you show all the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an instance of fPDF before creating your `footer` function.

```
require('fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF {
    //
    // This class extends FPDF so we may customize the header and footer
    // of the PDFs that are created
    //

    function Footer() {
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);   
    }  // end of the Footer function
}  // end of the PDF class
```